# FullCalendar.io - Get All Events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using the standard FullCalendar Events(as a json feed) and have everything working fine...almost.

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

My initial view is a 'dayGridMonth' so the FC default behavior is to only retrieve the events for that month by appending the startParm/endParam querystring.

This is not what I want.

On the backend of this request, I'm currently sending the **entire** calendar feed (ignoring the start/end params) so I don't have to keep hitting my AJAX '/myfeed.php' page every time somebody clicks on "Next" to view the next month.

However, I can't get FullCalendar to know that it already has the whole json feed and not to bother getting anything else - just show the next month from the data we have.  I've played around with lazyFetching but that seems to force that it goes to the AJAX call every time.

Any ideas on how I do this?

Thx!

Comment: `so I don't have to keep hitting my AJAX '/myfeed.php' page every time somebody clicks on "Next" to view the next month`...yeah, this _sounds_ like a good idea doesn't it? But what about when your site has been around for a while and that feed returns hundreds or thousands of events, the vast majority of which the user will never look at? This will slow down the calendar and also the server-side code. At that point you'll be glad fullcalendar works the way it does. And unless your code is hugely inefficient, these little ajax calls to fetch a few events will scarcely impact your server at all.